# How to check multiplicity in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, multiplicity

does anybody know the answer?
For instance, I have a div container and several items in it:

```
<div class="row">
  {% for item in filtered %}
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In the above code I need  to have only 3 images, so for the next images in a loop it should create new DIV, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

The issue is: I have iterating images and also should have iterating div.row, because I need only 3 images per div. I was looking for an answer everywhere, but no luck. So basically I need to check multiplicity in {{ forloop.counter }} I think. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help people help you if you show your actual template code.  Not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divisible by filter could be helpful or the cycle filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins